# Using data attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to use the data attribute to change the page to details about the selected product in my index web page. 
These are the functions that I am using at the moment. This works but it will only display the innerHTML of the document. Whereas i want all of the data about the object that is stored in a data attribute called `data-detail`. The responseText would be something similar to this:

`data-detail='{"ID":"1", "Name":"Some Name", "Description":"Some Description", "Price":"100", "Photo":"SomePath/AnotherPath/Image.png"}'`

```
function displayItems(results){
  article = document.getElementById("homeSection");
  string = '<h1>Company Name</h1><h2>Why not try these products?</h2>';
  for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    var price = parseFloat(results[i].Price);

    var sec = document.createElement("section");
    sec.classList.add("homeItem");
    sec.dataset.detail = JSON.stringify(results[i]);
    article.appendChild(sec);
    sec.innerHTML = '<div class="imageContainer"><img class="resultsImage" src="' + results[i].Photo + '"></div><p class="resultsName">' + results[i].Name + '</p><p class="resultsPrice">£' + price.toFixed(2) + '</p>';
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".homeItem");
    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
      items[i].addEventListener("click", selectedProduct);
    }
  }
}


function selectedProduct(event){
  target = event.currentTarget;
  homeSection = document.getElementById("homeSection");
  console.log(target.detail.ID);
  homeSection.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
}
```

After clicking on an element, the console is telling me that data.detail is undefined after parsing through the 3rd line down in the `selectedProduct` function. I wonder if anyone could tell me why this is and if I am being silly and not spotting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can store only string values, So after getting the value, you need to convert back to object by calling JSON.parse(). You also need to use dataset to get the value as you are setting the value.

```
function selectedProduct(event){
  target = event.currentTarget;
  homeSection = document.getElementById("homeSection");
  console.log(JSON.parse(target.dataset.detail).ID);
  homeSection.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I have changed that and now getting this error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`